# How to make fullpage.js section movement from left to right?

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js for my website. While I click on navigation it content move in from bottom. Is there any way to make it move in from right or from left?

Comment: please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. Use a single section with multiple slides inside:

```
<dic class="section">
    <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
```

Then create links to your slides by using the anchors in the URL.

[This website using fullpage.js](http://www.restaurantwoods.nl/) is a great example of what you are looking for, just check its source code.